# Issue with js loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need help, I’m new to js and have to do this task. I’m confused what I’m doing wrong…

```js
var products = [
  product = {
    id: 1,
    name: "green",
  },
  product = {
    id: 2,
    name: "red",
  },
  product = {
    id: 3,
    name: "black",
  },
];

var myWishlist = [
  wishlist = {
    id: 1,
    productId: 4,
  },
  wishlist = {
    id: 2,
    productId: 2,
  },
  wishlist = {
    id: 3,
    productId: 2,
  },
];

for (var i = 0; i < myWishlist.length; ++i) {
  var currentWishlistProductId = myWishlist[i].productId;
  for (var j = 0; j < products.length; ++j) {
    var currentProductId = products[i].id;
    if (currentWishlistProductId == currentProductId) {
      console.log(
        "Whishlist id: " +
        myWishlist[i].id +
        "Product name: " +
        products[i].name,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Now output is: Whishlist id: 2 Product name: red

Output should look like this:

Whishlist id: 2 Product name: red

Whishlist id: 3 Product name: red

Comment: (product = {
id: 1,
name: “green”,
}) , why have you given round brackets?

Comment: Please add the actual code you are using. Your example contains several syntax errors and does not output anything but an error message.

Comment: @str I added actual code

Comment: Your code has a filter `currentWishlistProductId == currentProductId`, there is no productId is `3` in `myWishlist`, so the line you want will not displayed. Try to replace `productId ` from 2 to 3 in the last item in `myWishlist`, you will get the output you want!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```js
var products = [{ id: 1, name: "green" }, { id: 2, name: "red" }, { id: 3, name: "black" }],
    myWishlist = [{ id: 1, productId: 4 }, { id: 2, productId: 2 }, { id: 3, productId: 2 }],
    res = products.map(function (item) {
          myWishlist.map(function (wishItem) {
              if(item.id == wishItem.productId){
                   console.log("Whishlist id: "+wishItem.id+" Product name: "+item.name)
              }
          });
    });
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it. If you did not mean to create an array, use forEach instead of map

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a data structure which is free of syntactic errors. You may have a look to [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and put the objects inside of an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) without assigning to a variable (which makes no sense).

The a good idea is to use a data structure which gives the opportunity to have a fast access to data with a key, like an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The later one accepts any type of variable as key and as value.

At last, you need only a single loop and get the wanted property from the mapped object.

```js
var products = [{ id: 1, name: "green" }, { id: 2, name: "red" }, { id: 3, name: "black" }],
    myWishlist = [{ id: 1, productId: 4 }, { id: 2, productId: 2 }, { id: 3, productId: 2 }],
    productsMap = new Map(products.map(o => [o.id, o]));

for (var i = 0; i < myWishlist.length; ++i) {
    console.log("Whishlist id:", myWishlist[i].id, "Product name:", (productsMap.get(myWishlist[i].productId) || {}).name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "j" iterator for products array

```
var products = [
  product = {
    id: 1,
    name: "green",
  },
  product = {
    id: 2,
    name: "red",
  },
  product = {
    id: 3,
    name: "black",
  },
];

var myWishlist = [
  wishlist = {
    id: 1,
    productId: 4,
  },
  wishlist = {
    id: 2,
    productId: 2,
  },
  wishlist = {
    id: 3,
    productId: 2,
  },
];
for (var i = 0; i < myWishlist.length; ++i) {
  var currentWishlistProductId = myWishlist[i].productId;
  for (var j = 0; j < products.length; ++j) {
    var currentProductId = products[j].id; // change i-> j
    if (currentWishlistProductId == currentProductId) {
      console.log(
        "Whishlist id: " +
        myWishlist[i].id +
        "Product name: " +
        products[j].name, // Change i->j
      );
    }
  }
}
```